# Grouping Layers on ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online

I have routes for the days of week (i.e. Monday rt1, rt2, rt3; Tuesday rt1, rt2, rt3; etc). I want to publish to ArcGIS online so that the user can look at all the Monday routes, for example, and click off or on all all the other routes for the rest of the week. I then also want the user to be able to turn off or on certain routes for the day of interest. The easiest way to do this would be to make group layers but ArcGIS Online doesn't support this. Should I publish each day of routes as it's own service and then add these services to a web map? Seems like there'd be a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either publish all the different routes per day as their own service or use the filtering option within the webmap to show selected days/routes.